# killing process in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need to kill all the process on the remote host with owner as "user1"

I am using command:

```
ps -efww | grep "user1"| awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

But the problem is that I have used same user "user1" to ssh to the remote machine.
and executing this command also kills the sshd process.

Can any one help me with this command, so that all the other process except the one for ssh is killed.

Comment: Add an extra grep excluding everything to do with ssh.

Comment: learn about `pgrep` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the sshd process by piping `| grep -v "sshd"`.

Comment: I have tried that but it does not works...  ps -efww | grep "user1" | grep -v "sshd" | awk '{print $2}' gives me all the processes to kill but : ps -efww | grep "user1" | grep -v "sshd" | awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill does not kills the processes.

Comment: You need to `xargs kill` (not `xargs`)